# How does Python evaluate this expression?

Tags: python, syntax

How does Python evaluate the following expression? `anim1` gets executed after `anim2`. How does a simple + operator that?

```
anim1 = Animation(duration=1, center=(100,100) type='delta')
anim2 = Animation(duration=1, rotation=45 type='delta')

anim = anim1 + anim2
```

Comment: What is "Animation"? You're going to have to provide more information, because the behavior you're describing depends completely on your class definition and not on Python's syntax.

Comment: Animation is a predefined class in an API.

Comment: Personally I think hacking `__add__` to make `+` do something like this is a horrible abuse.

Comment: "anim1 gets executed after anim2"  That's not really syntax.  That's semantics.  The question is "what does `+` mean"?  Not "how is `+` parsed"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will call `anim1.__add__(anim2)`.

In order to understand what is happening under the hood you have to inspect the definition of `__add__` method from Animation class.

Comment: It might even call `anim2.__radd__(anim1)` although that's very unlikely in this case.

Answer (score 3):

In Python, you can redefine the behavior of the mathematical operators. If I understood your question, Animation probably redefines the "+" operator using the `__add__` method.

More info: [Official Documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`dis` module](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html). It has a function `dis` that will take a function/module/class and show you the byte code.